# Why does Kernel#p duplicate my text on standard output?

Tags: ruby, io

Look at this code :

```
def hello
   p "Hey!"
end
p hello
```

the output will be:

```
"Hey!"
"Hey!"
=> "Hey!"
```

And so here is my conclusion: puts itself returns the text which is going to be sent in output in Ruby code, else it wouldn't print "Hey!" again. What is happening while printing the string? If puts doesn't send it to standard output directly, who is responsible for it and how?

Comment: You don't have any `puts` in your code. Why are you mentioning `puts`?

Comment: @sawa Probably because the OP thinks `p` is just shorthand for `puts`. It's not an uncommon mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### All Methods Return a Value

In Ruby, almost everything returns a value, even if that value is *nil*. However, in your case the issue is that [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p) and [Kernel#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) differ in the values they return.

```
def hello
   # Print string literal, then return
   # the printed object.
   p "Hey!"
end

# Print the return value of main#hello.
p hello
```

As a result, the string gets printed once inside the method, and then the method's return value is passed to Kernel#p and printed again. This is by design.

#### Use Kernel#puts to Avoid Duplicated Output

```
def hello
   # Print string; return nil.
   puts "Hey!"
end

# Calls main#hello, but prints nil (blank line).
puts hello
```

This will result in the string literal being printed inside the method, and then a blank line printed since the return value from the method is nil.

```
Hey!

=> nil
```

#### The Right Way

If you want to avoid the blank line, avoid sending to standard output more than once. For example:

```
def hello
  'Hey!'
end

p hello
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `p` method returns the string it's given, then `hello` would return that as well, which means that the secondary `p` call would repeat it.

This is probably why `puts` returns `nil` by default.

Comment: So you mean the puts first sends the text to output and after that returns it? Why? When this is needed? ( returning the puts method input)

Comment: It's just what the `p` method does. Why are you using that method, anyway? It's only useful inside `irb`. `puts` is the preferred output method.